# iOS crashlog iPad sqlite mutex lock

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, crash-log

how can I understand, at which position in my App, the App aborts.
If I start the App on other iPads it works great, only on one, I get the following crash log:
Is the following crash-log correct symbolized and when not, how to do it right? I get this crash-log from mail an imported it with Xcode.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: com.qi.DWA exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 17.62 seconds |  | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 9.200 (user 9.200, system 0.000), 23% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 5.117, 13% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180f2d734 guarded_pwrite_np + 8
System_Collections_Generic_List_1_T_GSHAREDVT_InsertRange_int_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_1_T_GSHAREDVT (in XXX.iOS) + 992
System_Tuple_2_T1_GSHAREDVT_T2_GSHAREDVT_get_Item2 (in XXX.iOS) + 108
System_Collections_ObjectModel_Collection_1_T_GSHAREDVT_RemoveAt_int (in XXX.iOS) + 240
System_Runtime_CompilerServices_ConditionalWeakTable_2_TKey_GSHAREDVT_TValue_GSHAREDVT_GetValue_TKey_GSHAREDVT_System_Runtime_CompilerServices_ConditionalWeakTable_2_CreateValueCallback_TKey_GSHAREDVT_TValue_GSHAREDVT (in XXX.iOS) + 204
native_to_managed_trampoline_127(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, UIView*, unsigned int) (in XXX.iOS) (registrar.m:6493)
-[Plugin_Media_MediaPickerPopoverDelegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:] (in XXX.iOS) (registrar.m:12055)
native_to_managed_trampoline_103(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, UISplitViewController*, UIViewController*, unsigned int) (in XXX.iOS) (registrar.m:5092)
native_to_managed_trampoline_102(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, UISplitViewController*, unsigned int) (in XXX.iOS) (registrar.m:5041)
native_to_managed_trampoline_107(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, UISplitViewController*, UIViewController*, UIBarButtonItem*, unsigned int) (in XXX.iOS) (registrar.m:5317)
native_to_managed_trampoline_38(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, UIActionSheet*, long, unsigned int) (in XXX.iOS) (registrar.m:1739)
native_to_managed_trampoline_33(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, UITableView*, unsigned int) (in XXX.iOS) (registrar.m:1492)
native_to_managed_trampoline_30(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, UITableView*, unsigned int) (in XXX.iOS) (registrar.m:1310)
native_to_managed_trampoline_29(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, UITableView*, long, unsigned int) (in XXX.iOS) (registrar.m:1259)
14  XXX.iOS                         0x00000001019f3e30 wrapper_managed_to_native_SQLitePCL_SQLite3Provider_sqlite3_NativeMethods_sqlite3_prepare_v2_intptr_intptr_int_intptr__intptr_ + 20512304 (/<unknown>:1)
15  XXX.iOS                         0x00000001019ee10c SQLitePCL_SQLite3Provider_sqlite3_SQLitePCL_ISQLite3Provider_sqlite3_prepare_v2_intptr_string_intptr__string_ + 20488460 (/<unknown>:1)
16  XXX.iOS                         0x00000001019e27d0 SQLitePCLRaw_core_SQLitePCL_raw_sqlite3_prepare_v2_SQLitePCL_sqlite3_string_SQLitePCL_sqlite3_stmt__string_ + 120
17  XXX.iOS                         0x00000001019e274c SQLitePCLRaw_core_SQLitePCL_raw_sqlite3_prepare_v2_SQLitePCL_sqlite3_string_SQLitePCL_sqlite3_stmt_ + 24
18  XXX.iOS                         0x00000001019b1c70 SQLite_net_SQLite_SQLiteCommand_Prepare + 20241520 (SQLite.cs:3437)
19  XXX.iOS                         0x00000001019b1634 SQLite_net_SQLite_SQLiteCommand_ExecuteNonQuery + 20239924 (SQLite.cs:2227)
20  XXX.iOS                         0x00000001019ad1e0 SQLite_net_SQLite_SQLiteConnection_Execute_string_object__ + 20222432 (SQLite.cs:659)
21  XXX.iOS                         0x00000001019ac390 SQLite_net_SQLite_SQLiteConnection_CreateTable_System_Type_SQLite_CreateFlags + 20218768 (SQLite.cs:422)
22  XXX.iOS                         0x00000001019ac04c SQLite_net_SQLite_SQLiteConnection_CreateTable_T_REF_SQLite_CreateFlags + 20217932 (SQLite.cs:378)
23  XXX.iOS                         0x000000010140d160 XXX_XXX_sync_syncWebdienst_createDatabase + 14324064 (.C:\csvn\XXX-Crossover_V3\XXX\XXX\XXX\sync\syncWebdienst.cs:55)
24  XXX.iOS                         0x00000001013a71e4 XXX_XXX_App__ctor + 13906404 (.C:\csvn\XXX-Crossover_V3\XXX\XXX\XXX\App.cs:53)
25  XXX.iOS                         0x0000000100691414 XXX_iOS_XXX_iOS_AppDelegate_FinishedLaunching_UIKit_UIApplication_Foundation_NSDictionary + 72
26  XXX.iOS                         0x000000010071d734 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
27  XXX.iOS                         0x00000001023b984c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 30758988 (mini-runtime.c:2768)
28  XXX.iOS                         0x0000000102421050 do_runtime_invoke + 31182928 (object.c:2862)
29  XXX.iOS                         0x0000000102420fb0 mono_runtime_invoke + 31182768 (object.c:3016)
30  XXX.iOS                         0x000000010066b5c4 native_to_managed_trampoline_16(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, UIApplication*, NSDictionary*, unsigned int) + 30148 (registrar.m:678)
31  XXX.iOS                         0x000000010066bc10 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 31760 (registrar.m:7187)
32  UIKit                           0x000000018f7f02c4 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 384
33  UIKit                           0x000000018f9e1bc4 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3436
34  UIKit                           0x000000018f9e6a14 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1712
35  UIKit                           0x000000018fc822a8 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 800
36  UIKit                           0x000000018ff5a100 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
37  UIKit                           0x000000018fc81f0c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 252
38  UIKit                           0x000000018fc8276c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 732
39  UIKit                           0x00000001904077c0 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 260
40  UIKit                           0x0000000190407664 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
41  UIKit                           0x00000001901752cc __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
42  UIKit                           0x000000019030e3cc _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
43  UIKit                           0x000000019017517c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 252
44  UIKit                           0x000000018ff59760 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 364
45  UIKit                           0x000000018f9e5158 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
46  UIKit                           0x000000018fdfadbc -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364
```

What is the Problem, can anyone help me?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

After right symbolication i updated my crash-log.
The database on the Tablet is 5,5 GB big. In syncWebdienst.cs 55, the App createDataTable, means, that the sqlite look if the table have changes or is new.

Answer (score 0):

Your crash log is not symbolicated. You probably do not have archive with that build that produced crash.

Anyway, reason for crash seems to be that your code blocked main thread for more than 10 seconds, and system killed your app.

Comment: And how do I symbolicate it right?

What can I do, that the App doesnt Crash. Because on other iPads it works perfectly.